# Firebase crash batch upload fail for unknown reason

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm trying to upload DSYM s to firebase, which worked perfectly till a few days before. When I start the script, and it s start loggin, a few lines after it stuck for a few minutes and then fails.

```
/Users/..../dSYMs/DF...C47.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/leveldb: warning: function at offset 0x51662 has no name
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym-util.bash:365: error: upload: Unable to upload symbol file (reason unknown).
```

The interesting thing is, in firebase console it tells me the upload was successful:

> Future stack traces for UUID B4...AAF will
>   be symbolicated using the uploaded symbol file.

But it never, because I ve "uploaded" a few like this, and since that, I had a few more crashes, but still not symbolicated...

What's going on?

FYI: I'm using firebase crashreporting since February, and it worked nicely. I updated my mac to High Sierra a few days ago.

Thy

Comment: There's a known issue in High Sierra where some symbol uploads don't succeed. I suspect it's an issue having to due with an upgraded command line utility that causes our invocation syntax now be invalid. Once we're able to upgrade to High Sierra, I'll be able to fix this issue. In the meantime, you could also try out Crashlytics.

Comment: I also get the same, after ugrading to High Sierra and Xcode 9.2

Comment: @mike_haney I see, do you have any information about, when ll be fixed? Because we really need the crash reports :)

Comment: We did look into it some, but most likely this will be fixed sometime early in the new year.

Comment: I'm working with another developer on this repo to diagnose: https://github.com/UglyBlueCat/quickstart-ios

feel free to help/comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR

Look for the following line in `upload-sym-util.bash`:

```
HTTP_STATUS=$(curl ${CURLOPT} -sfL -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -H "Authorization: Bearer ${BEARER_TOKEN}" -w '%{http_code}' -T "${FILE}" "${UPLOAD_URL}")
```

And append `--http1.1` at the end so that it becomes:

```
HTTP_STATUS=$(curl ${CURLOPT} -sfL -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -H "Authorization: Bearer ${BEARER_TOKEN}" -w '%{http_code}' -T "${FILE}" "${UPLOAD_URL}" --http1.1)
```

### Explanation

We have been having this issue when uploading the DSYM files on Firebase via **XCode**. What was driving us crazy was that the process seemed to randomly succeed and fail. When the upload failed, it did after a few minutes.

We managed to run the offending `curl` command manually and discovered that it was returning an HTTP status code of 000 which seems to happen when the connection is closed before the server actually returns anything (eg: timeout). By using the `--verbose` argument we discovered that `curl` was aborting the call with an `INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)` which seemed to be linked with the use of HTTP/2. We managed to confirm this when we found out that the only machine that was able to upload the DSYM files correctly had the same version of `curl` as everyone else but with no HTTP/2 support, which was apparently added in **High Sierra**. We forced `curl` to use HTTP1.1 and it did the trick.

Comment: Thx for your response. After I tried what you suggested, the build script fails with : --http1.1: command not found          Upload: unable to upload symbol file (reason unknown)

Comment: This only fails if I try to build the app from XCode. It not fails if I'm trying to upload a DSYM from terminal, but it still stucks and then fails with the same reason as I mentioned in my question

Comment: I'm sorry, the `--http1.1` argument should have been inside the command substitution (`$(...)`), I've edited my answer. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: Good news, it works for me too. I hope it gonna work in the future. Thank you, nice job!